# How to extract members of an array into individual parameters without knowing them beforehand?

Tags: php, eval

I wrote some kind of global logger class for a project and want to access the internal log()-method with a helper function. The log() method uses vsprintf to allow for simple message formatting. This works fine, but now I am encountering difficulties in passing on the parameters from the helper function into the logger's log() method.

```
function writeLog($severity, $message)
{
  $args = func_get_args();
  $arg_string = '';
  foreach ($args as $k => $v)
  {
    $arg_string .= '$args['.$k.'], ';
  }

  $arg_string = substr($arg_string, 0, -2);

  Logger::getLogger()->log(eval($arg_string));
}
```

In my opinion, using `eval()` on those argument strings should do what I want. But somehow, I keep getting errors like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in Logger.php(19) : eval()'d code on line 1`
(The argument strings generated look like `$args[0], $args[1], $args[2]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, I think, should do the trick

```
function writeLog($severity, $message) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $logger = Logger::getLogger();
    call_user_func_array(array(logger, 'log'), $args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `eval()`/argument passing works.

What you probably want is something like [`call_user_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function writeLog($severity, $message) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array(array(Logger::getLogger(), 'log'), $args)
}
```

Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php